# Error in c# function while using swith statement inside

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I got a problem with my C# code and I really do not know, why there is an error! In my opinion it shoudl work, but it doesn`t. It doesn`t even compile. That is the function:

```
public bool AddColumn(string tableName, string colName, ColType colType)
    {
        switch(colType) 
        {
            ColType.MYSQL_DOUBLE:   
                                    Console.Write("DOUBLE");
            ColType.MYSQL_INT:      
                                    Console.Write("INT");
            default:                
                                    Console.Write("DEFAULT");
        }
          return true;
    }
```

The error says, theres a missing ';' and '}'. So if If try to comment in content of the function like:

```
public bool AddColumn(string tableName, string colName, ColType colType)
    {/*
        switch(colType) 
        {
            ColType.MYSQL_DOUBLE:   
                                    Console.Write("DOUBLE");
            ColType.MYSQL_INT:      
                                    Console.Write("INT");
            default:                
                                    Console.Write("DEFAULT");
        }*/
          return true;
    }
```

I can compile the program. Hence there is a problem with inside of the switch statement, isn`t it? Hope someone can help me out of this...

FYI the type 'ColType is declared inside the program:

```
public enum ColType
    {
        MYSQL_DOUBLE = 0,
        MYSQL_INT = 1
    };
```

Comment: A switch without `case`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `case` keyword in `switch` and also put `break` in each case, its worth looking on documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

```
switch(colType) 
{
     case ColType.MYSQL_DOUBLE:   
              Console.Write("DOUBLE");
              break;
     case ColType.MYSQL_INT:      
              Console.Write("INT");
              break;
     default:                
              Console.Write("DEFAULT");
              break;
 }
```

Comment: Wow, it`s awesome...how could I miss that...shame on me :D. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Proper switch case in c#

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/06tc147t.aspx

```
int caseSwitch = 1;
switch (caseSwitch)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Default case");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You´re missing the `case`- and `break`-statements to differ the cases within your switch:

```
switch(colType) 
{
    case ColType.MYSQL_DOUBLE:   
        Console.Write("DOUBLE");
        break;
    case ColType.MYSQL_INT:      
        Console.Write("INT");
        break;
    default:                
        Console.Write("DEFAULT");
        break;
}
```

Also consider this:

> Execution of the statement list in the selected switch section begins
>   with the first statement and proceeds through the statement list,
>   typically until a jump statement, such as a break, goto case, return,
>   or throw, is reached.At that point, control is transferred outside the
>   switch statement or to another case label. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/06tc147t.aspx)

This means while `case` will indicate the begin of a switch-case `break` (or any other statement that interupt execution such as `return` or `throw`) indicates its end.

Comment: that would be too easy;). I already tried it. It does not solve the problem. I got the same error.

Comment: Did you also add the `case`?